# Trait std::convert::From<String> not implemented for hyper::body::Body

Tags: rust, traits, rust-warp

```
lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref file_data: String = fs::read_to_string("static/login.html").expect("unable to read from static/login.html");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // code omitted
    let login = warp::path("login").map(move || warp::reply::html(file_data));
    // code omitted
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `hyper::body::body::Body: std::convert::From<file_data>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:45:49
    |
45  |     let login = warp::path("login").map(move || warp::reply::html(file_data));
    |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<file_data>` is not implemented for `hyper::body::body::Body`
    | 
   ::: /home/ichi/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.2.3/src/reply.rs:170:11
    |
170 |     Body: From<T>,
    |           ------- required by this bound in `warp::reply::html`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<&'static [u8]>>
              <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<&'static str>>
              <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<bytes::bytes::Bytes>>
              <hyper::body::body::Body as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'static, [u8]>>>
            and 4 others
```

I am trying to pass a `String` to a closure. According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.13.6/hyper/body/struct.Body.html#impl-From%3CString%3E), `From<String>` is implemented for `hyper::body::Body` and `file_data` is of type `String`. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/)

> For a given `static ref NAME: TYPE = EXPR;`, the macro generates a unique type that implements `Deref<TYPE>` and stores it in a static with name `NAME`. (Attributes end up attaching to this type.)

That is, the type of the variable is *not* `TYPE`!

This is why you see the error

```
the trait `std::convert::From<file_data>` is not implemented for `hyper::body::body::Body`
                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

You'd probably have better luck explicitly de-referencing or cloning the global variable: `warp::reply::html(&*file_data)` or `warp::reply::html(file_data.clone())`.

Comment: Using `*` to dereference the value wouldn't help here because you can't move from a `lazy_static` and `String` isn't `Copy`.

Comment: It might also be worth clarifying the difference between `&*` and `.clone()` - i.e. passing a reference to static data vs copying it into a new value. `.as_str()` may also be a more clear and idiomatic equivalent to `&*`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `lazy_static` creates a wrapper type that references your data, and `hyper` doesn't know how to handle it. You could use `file_data.clone()` to clone the referenced data and construct a body from that, but in this case there's actually a simpler method. Since your string has a fixed value and `Body` implements `From<&'static str>`, you don't actually need a heap-allocated `String` or `lazy_static` at all: You can use the following code which just uses a constant string slice that can be used directly.

```
const FILE_DATA: &str = "test";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // code omitted
    let login = warp::path("login").map(move || warp::reply::html(FILE_DATA));
    // code omitted
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question, String::from() was just for demonstration, I am actually reading String from file thus I cant have &str